# Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/package-name

Tags: javascript, git, github, github-actions, github-package-registry

I'm trying to upload a package on GPR (Github Package registry). I log in successfully:

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

and then run these command:

```
npm set registry https://npm.pkg.github.com/

npm publish
```

which returns this error:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/package-name
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'package-name@version' is not in the npm registry.
```

Seems it tries to upload a package on npm registry instead of github package registry. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?  Are you specifying the `publishConfig.registry` there?  Remarkably, specifying the registry on the command line does not override that.

Comment: No, I don't specify `publishConfig` field in package.json at all

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Specify `publishConfig` option in `package.json`:

```js
"publishConfig": {
    "registry":"https://npm.pkg.github.com/@OWNER"
},
```

2. Add `.npmrc` file to your project with this content:

```sh
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/@OWNER
```

replacing `OWNER` with the name of the user or organization account on GitHub that owns the repository where you will publish the package.

Comment: it's solved the problem, but i have new problem 
```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Yes, just added property of repository in package.json, point to your repo at github.

Comment: @yussan How did you figure out `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: @SereneAbrahamMathew i got it on my console

Comment: @yussan i mean how did you fix it

Comment: @SereneAbrahamMathew i added new property on package json
```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git"
  },
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 19):

For example:

```
{
  "name": "@elvisjs/calling-elvis",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/elvisjs/calling-elvis"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/elvisjs"
  }
}
```

The `name`, `repository/url` and the `publishConfig/registry` must be matched.

Comment: Thanks a lot I tried to understand why I can't publish for hours! Soooo weird, why I need to have a repository block for publishing??? And even don't get a nice error message and no clear description in docs for that. It is just crazy...

Comment: Your solution works for me too. But i need to add something, dont mix hyphen and under score like me :)

Answer (score 13):

Github Package registry expected the name properties on package.json to be "@{github username}/{package name}
for example:-

```
"name": "@pravanjan/local-time",
"publishConfig": { 
     "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/" 
 },
```

If "publishConfig" is not set in package.json we can directly set the registry parameter in terminal

```
npm publish --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

This did work for me

Answer (score 2):

As hinted by other answers here, the root cause of the above error is that GPR (unlike https://www.npmjs.com/) requires that packages have a scope.

However, it seems that all other suggested solutions (updating `package.json` and etc.) would not allow to keep publishing the package to https://www.npmjs.com/ without a scope.
Here's my solution that allows both:

Assuming that:

1. `package.json` contains simple package name without scope as often is the case when publishing public packages to https://www.npmjs.com/
2. GitHub Workflow is configured using GitHub's *Node.js Package* template

Add additional step to `publish-gpr` job before the `run: npm ci` default step in order to dynamically insert current repository's owner into package name in `package.json`:

```
- name: Insert repository owner as scope into package name
  run: |
    node <<EOF
    const fs = require('fs').promises;
    fs.readFile('package.json', 'utf8').then((data) => JSON.parse(data)).then((json) => {
        json.name = '@$(echo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" | sed 's/\/.\+//')/' + json.name;
        console.info('Package name changed to %s', json.name);
        return fs.writeFile('package.json', JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
    EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1) To publish into github package registry*** (https://npm.pkg.github.com/) through github workflow, 3 files have to configured correctly.

Step 1: From package root repository, create the file in ./github/workflows/release-package.yml Ensure the registry-url is https://npm.pkg.github.com/. Refer to https://github.com/vernGlobe/json-light-query/blob/main/.github/workflows/release-package.yml

Step 2: Configure in "package.json":

```
"name": "@<username>/json-light-query",
"publishConfig": {
   "@<username>:registry":"https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
 }
```

Step 3: Add into the file ".npmrc":

```
@<username>:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

Note: replace `<username>` with your GitHub account username.

***Option 2: Publish into npm package registry*** (https://registry.npmjs.org/). Only package.json file need to configure correctly.

```
"name": "json-light-query",
"publishConfig": {
    "@<username>:registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
}
```

Note: replace `<username>` with your npmjs account username.

Download/Search the package from https://www.npmjs.com/